# Test content from child component with router

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi I want check render from h1 on my child component. I have a `null` when I want get `h1` tag.

My test :

```
fdescribe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent,
        MenuComponent,
        UsersComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AddUserComponent ],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, 
      RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)],
      providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }]
  }).compileComponents();
}));

it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  console.error("COMPILED -> ", compiled.querySelector('h1'));
  expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Content');
}));
});
```

My router :

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
  { path: 'adduser', component: AddUserComponent }
];
```

My `appComponent.html` :

```
<pr-menu></pr-menu>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My `home.component.html`

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:  center">
   <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to find the doc with the “container” class? I’m wondering whether you’re injecting routing into your test correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have html content from container but I think my HomeComponent is not loaded.

Comment: You can check that by giving the containing div in HoneComponent another class aside from container. If you can’t find that then yes, it’s not getting rendered. One reason MIGHT be that TestBed only does Shallow rendering (as, for instance you can do in React/Enzyme testing), but I can’t make much sense of the docs.